# Why does golang strings.Builder implements String() like this?

Tags: go

The implementation is

```
// String returns the accumulated string.
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

According to my test, converting []byte to string uses "copy on write", or the compiler generates the deep copy instructions if either one is changing the insided slice:

```
{
        a := []byte{'a'}
        s1 := string(a)
        a[0] = 'b'
        fmt.Println(s1) // a
    }

    {
        a := "a"
        b := []byte(a)
        b[0] = 'b'
        fmt.Println(a) // a
    }
```

So what happens if it's implemented as below?

```
// String returns the accumulated string.
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return string(b.buf)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view the discussion on the changelist that introduced the `strings.Builder` api here: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/74931/4/src/strings/builder.go#30

As you'd expect, it's a discussion of API mechanics, correctness, and efficiency.

If you replace the code with `string(b.buf)`, you'll cause a copy of the built string. It may be that the compiler optimizes away the copy in simple cases of converting a byte slice to a string, but it's very unlikely that the compiler can do that here in general (because it would require a proof that the buffer inside the string builder is never used again).

Note that the (standard-library) code looks dangerous, because if you write this:

```
var b strings.Builder
b.WriteString("hello world")
c := b.String()
b.WriteString("a")
d := b.String()
```

then `c` and `d` will end up pointing to the same memory. But that's fine, because strings contain the length of their buffer. And there's no way to mutate a string, because even though in theory the memory backing the string is accessible via the `buf` in the `strings.Builder`, the only apis provided append to the backed memory.

Answer (score 9):

Given large enough strings the type conversion requires memory allocations whereas the conversion using the unsafe package does not:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

func BenchmarkConversion(b *testing.B) {
    buf := make([]byte, 16<<10)
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        var _ string = string(buf)
    }
}

func BenchmarkUnsafe(b *testing.B) {
    buf := make([]byte, 16<<10)
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        var _ string = *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf))
    }
}
```

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkConversion-8            307087      3897 ns/op     16384 B/op     1 allocs/op
BenchmarkUnsafe-8            1000000000     0.299 ns/op         0 B/op     0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      _/tmp/tmp.KECLzZwkUn    1.579s
```

Comment: Go is developed at google so you can expect it to be optimised for a Google type environment. I.E. fast servers with lots of memory and high reliability requirements. So they will always default to safety in a "resources vs. safety" conflict. Although the nice people at golang do give you an unsafe but fast option should you feel the need.

Comment: @JamesAnderson Although the String() method uses the `unsafe` package, the method is safe to use. The method makes an assumption about the memory layout of strings and slices.  The assumption is valid today and we can expect the Go team to update the String() method implementation should the Go team invalidate the assumption.